# GLM - X.intercept equal to NA

Tags: generalized-linear-model, missing-data

What does it mean X.Intercept equal to NA as a result of glm summary ? Thanks.

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)

```
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
```

(Intercept)     1.98e+02   4.72e+01    4.18  2.9e-05 ***

**X.Intercept.          NA         NA      NA       NA**

Answer (score 0):

My mystake was in not cutting off the first column of the model matrix, which is used as input to the glm() function.

my.model <- model.matrix(f, data=my.data)**[-1]**